# Can't open Drawer from stack header React native v5

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to open my drawer from my header, but i couldn't figure it out, here is a look at my code:

```
import { NavigationContainer,useNavigation,DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
.
.
.
render({ 
return (
      <Root>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>

        <Stack.Navigator >
          <Stack.Screen name="Mediclic" component={AppDraw}
            options={
              headerLeft: () =>
                <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer() }>
                  <MaterialIcons name='menu' size={28} color={'white'} />
                </TouchableOpacity>,
            }
            } />
</Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
 );
  }
}
const AppDraw = () =>

  <Drawer.Navigator>
    <Drawer.Screen name="Accueil" component={AccueilScreen} />
    <Drawer.Screen name="A propos" component={AboutScreen} />
  </Drawer.Navigator>
```

as you can see the stack navigator and the drawer are on the same file, but still couldn't make it work
on my case, i got TypoErro:undefined is not an object( navigation.opendrawer)

i also tried dispatch but it didn't work.

can somebody please help me i've been struggling with this for over a week!
thank you

Comment: Your drawer is inside the stack and the navigation at that point has no access to the drawer, better re order the component if possible

Comment: like whats wrong with it? what can i do?

Comment: Drawer is generally the parent , any reason to have the drawer inside the stack ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved the problem only by using this:

```
onPress={() =>  
navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer()) }
```

if anyone using drawer navigation V5, i recommend using this!

Comment: Not working in V6

Answer (score 0):

make drawer child of the screen where you want to open drawer
let suppose i want to open drawer in AccueilScreen.

what i do in your code

use

children={this.AppDraw} instead of component={AppDraw}
and write

```
<Stack.Screen name="Accueil" children={this.AppDraw}
```

instead of

```
<Stack.Screen name="Mediclic" component={AppDraw}
```

try this i hope its helpfull for you

```
 import { NavigationContainer,useNavigation,DrawerActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
    .
    .
    .
    render({ 
    return (
          <Root>
          <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
    
            <Stack.Navigator >
              <Stack.Screen name="Accueil" children={this.AppDraw}
                options={
                  headerLeft: () =>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft: 5 }} onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer() }>
                      <MaterialIcons name='menu' size={28} color={'white'} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>,
                }
                } />
    </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
     );
      }
    }
     AppDraw = () =>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Accueil" component={AccueilScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="A propos" component={AboutScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: ok no problem i wil share you example of my drawer because i dont know about your code screens